create generic/dynamic event rule for multiple events detail-type in aws eventbridge
We have a lot of event detail-type. We need an event rule to trigger the "notify" event detail-type. Here are the list of all possible event detail-type:
com.expert.efg.input-portfolio-created:v1
com.expert.efg.published-portfolio-created:v1
com.expert.efg.published-portfolio:v1
com.expert.efg.portfolio-preparation.tolerance-check.notify.failure:v1 
com.expert.efg.portfolio-preparation.tolerance-check.notify.success:v1
com.expert.efg.portfolio-preparation.apply-threshold.notify.success:v1
com.expert.efg.portfolio-preparation.apply-threshold.notify.failure:v1
com.expert.efg.published-portfolio.mi-report.notify.success:v1
com.expert.efg.published-portfolio.mi-report.notify.failure:v1

We need a custom event rule which is generic enough to trigger the following events detail-type (having "notify") and block all other event detail-type.
com.expert.efg.portfolio-preparation.tolerance-check.notify.failure:v1 
com.expert.efg.portfolio-preparation.tolerance-check.notify.success:v1
com.expert.efg.portfolio-preparation.apply-threshold.notify.success:v1
com.expert.efg.portfolio-preparation.apply-threshold.notify.failure:v1
com.expert.efg.published-portfolio.mi-report.notify.success:v1
com.expert.efg.published-portfolio.mi-report.notify.failure:v1


I used wildcard option to fix the issue. The event rule is as below:
{
"detail": {
"id": [{
"exists": true
}],
"source": [{
"exists": true
}],
"specversion": [{
"exists": true
}],
"type": [{
"exists": true
}]
},
"detail-type": [{
"wildcard": "com.expert.efg.*.notify.*"
}],
"source": [
"source"
]
}


reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-pattern-operators.html
